# Zend_Form submit stops working, when displayed with Display Groups

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

My Zend_Form has only two elements, text and submit.

When I render the Form as whole, everything works fine.

```
echo $this->form;
```

When I render the Form part by part, it gets rendered, but the submit button triggers nothing.

```
echo $this->form->range;
echo $this->form->submit;
```

Rendering wiht display groups also leaves the submit button dead.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When not just echo'ing `$this->form` are you creating a `<form>` tag with the correct method and action?  If you output form fields individually, you also need to do the <form> tag yourself.  Maybe post all or more of the view script code for your form.

Comment: but using display groups should handle the <form> tags... even then the submit button is still dead...

Comment: look at the generated HTML - i had no problems with fieldsets/displaygroups so far using Zend_Form - look at the generated HTML and in case of error we need your Form.php, too

Comment: @krzysiek I'm not sure I agree that display groups should handle the form tags if you are rending your elements individually.  As Sam said, check your html output, show us that if necessary and post some more of your view scripts code for rendering the form as well as the form code.

Comment: In the meantime I got familiar with decorators : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you echo form object its magic function __toString() gets called which outputs the html generated by default registered decorators . Which includes "" html tag . Which wraps up all the elements added to the zend from . So if you are echoing individual elements you need to manually wrap elements inside html form tag .